# how to make linq to display records that are two years old

Tags: vb.net, linq

How can I make a linq query to get my records of the past 2 years. The main problem right now is that the datagrid loads to many records and that it gets slow, so i am trying to reduce that amount  by getting the records of the last 2 years. I have searched, but don't seem to know what I can use or should use.
I remember doing it in Mysql, but I don't seem to find those options in Linq. I am pretty sure linq can do it too, but i dont know how.

So can someone help me out with this ?

```
 dim getRecord = (From rec in DB.table
                 Where rec.date ....  ' no idea
                 Select rec.date).ToList()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like

```
Where rec.date > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2)
```

If you have a large number of records, don't forget to add an index on the date column

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim twoYearsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2);
dim getRecord = (From rec in DB.table 
                 Where rec.date >= twoYearsAgo
                 Select rec.date).ToList()
```